# tkz-euclide.sty not found

Tags: packages, installing

I'm very new to LaTex. 
I'm trying to complile a document that contains the following:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usetkzobj{all}
```

I'm getting `tkz-euclide.sty not found`.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.something. and I previously received `kmath.sty` not found, so I did a:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

hoping never to receive another `.sty` not found 
error again. 
This did resolved my `kmath.sty` not found issue, but not the `tkz-euclide.sty`.

I took a look at the process for installing individual .sty files from CTAN and it made open heart surgery look easier. I'm not excited about the prospect of trying the instructions I found.

and I also typed `texhash` many times, it did not solve my issue.

Comment: It is not a recent addition to TeX Live so it should be in the Ubuntu packages although I can't say which one. Use your package manager to see what other packages are available which might contain this.

Comment: `apt-get install texlive-pictures` should do, but I don't know whether it does with TeX Live/Debian 2009. First of all, upgrade to TL 2012.